# bash using getopts

Tags: linux, bash

Example of script usage

```
./foo.sh -v -r /home/ -s /home/user/file
./foo.sh -r /home/ -s /home/user/file
```

In parameter I always need a file or a folder to scan and a file for the database (-s database file)

inside foo.sh

```
function entrance()
{
while getopts "v:r:s" opt; do
  case $opt in
    v)
      echo "-v was triggered, Verbose mode" >&2
      ;;
    r)
      echo "-r was triggered, recursive mode: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    s)
      echo "-s was triggered, DATABASE: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Please fix me.

Thanks

Comment: Given your examples, your option string should be `getopts ":vr:s:"` -- with what you have, `-v` and `-r` require arguments and `-s` does not.

Comment: In what way does it not "work"? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot about $@ while calling the function. See this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function entrance() {
while getopts "v:r:s" opt; do
  case $opt in
    v)
      echo "-v was triggered, Verbose mode" >&2
      ;;
    r)
      echo "-r was triggered, recursive mode: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    s)
      echo "-s was triggered, DATABASE: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
}

entrance "$@"
```

And some explanation: [Using getopts within user-defined-function in bourne shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352044/using-getopts-within-user-defined-function-in-bourne-shell)

Comment: You should use double-quotes around `$@` to avoid problems with spaces or other metacharacters in the parameters.